# How to identify img file which is loaded under network monitor console using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firebug, firepath

When we navigate to a page and inspect the page, under Network monitor tab > images, we get a list of file names (Ex. imgge.png) as the page is loaded. How do i idientify the image is present when we navigate to a page using selenium script.
I have attached the screenshot for reference what im exactly referring to.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJfDl.png)

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12912/how-to-check-is-image-is-loaded-or-not-in-selenium

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("imagefile_id")).isDisplayed();
```

get the id value of the image and use the above script, it return the Boolean value.